# Share uncensored internet over wifi

Tags: vpn

In my country many websites are blocked. I use openvpn, ssh tennels and socks proxies on linux to access uncensored internet.

Is there a way I can share the uncensored internet over wifi so that other devices on my home network can access it? Foe example can I share my VPN connection over wifi?

There is an android softeware called Fqrouter2 that does the same thing. I wonder if that can be done in linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run the VPN client on the router (or the computer which acts as a router) then you can route all (or any selected) connections through the VPN.

With OpenVPN you can add

```
redirect-gateway
```

to the client configuration file to route all connections through the VPN, or

```
route destination.IP destination's.mask
```

to route connections to a given destination.

For example, Ask Ubuntu uses CloudFlare and IPs in the 104.16.0.0 - 104.31.255.255 range so to route all connections to AskUbuntu.com through the VPN, you would add

```
route 104.16.0.0 255.255.0.0
```

If this provides insufficient granularity, you can also issue arbitrary commands with

```
route-up "whatever command, for example /usr/sbin/ip route add ..."
```

which will be executed after the VPN connection is established. Make sure you set the appropriate `script-security` level.

Before that, you need to [share the connection over wifi](/questions/60980/how-to-share-a-wired-internet-connection-via-wifi) of course.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. The problem is I don't want/cant run openvpn on all the clients. I need them to access uncensored internet just by connecting to wifi. I'll try to install DD-wrt or something similar on my router but I whish there was an easier way to do this.

Comment: You only need to set up the client on the computer which acts as a router/AP. And yes,  you can do this on OpenWRT (same config as above since it's just Linux). It would make sense than keeping a PC running but this is Ask **Ubuntu**.